# how do i get nmea sentences on android when the API method does not work

Tags: android, nmea

I have the same problem related [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7321) on a Samsung galaxy spica and i tried all suggestions but i still don't get the nmea sentences in my application. 
So is there a other way to get the nmea sentences ? 
Is someone else facing this issue with the same device ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the NMEA apps available in the marketplace to see if those work.  If they do, then you are likely implementing the `NmeaListener` incorrectly as most of them probably use that method.  If you want to be sure, I know the app Field Tracer uses `NmeaListener` since I built that one myself.

If `NmeaListener` is proven to not be working on that device, you can try the app linked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6955277/756375) answer.

Worst case you could get a Bluetooth GPS device, as they typically send NMEA strings.  $100 for something like the Garmin Glo and as a bonus you get much better accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser this is usefull to know.  Altough I should find a way to close this subject. I am not working on this since a while ago.