# Display the NMEA sentence?

Tags: android

Any one help to display the NMEA sentence like $GPRMC .....
I am using the below code:

```
public class SampleNMEA extends Activity implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener,GpsStatus.NmeaListener{

    LocationManager lm;
    TextView output;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000,10,this);
        final Location location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        output.append("\nBelow Data is about the your location:");

        output.append("\n\n\nLatit:"+location.getLatitude());
        output.append("\n\nLongitude:"+location.getLongitude());
        output.append("\n\nTime: "+location.getTime());


    }
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        output.append("\n\n\nLatitude:"+location.getLatitude());
        output.append("\n\nLongitude:"+location.getLongitude());
        output.append("\n\nTime: "+location.getTime());
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) 
    {
         lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000,10,this);
        final Location location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        output.append("\n\n\nLatitude:"+location.getLatitude());
        output.append("\n\nLongitude:"+location.getLongitude());
        output.append("\n\nTime: "+location.getTime());


}

    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) 
    {

    }
    public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) 
    {
        output.append("NMEA Sentence: "+nmea);

    }

    }
```

Any one help I added permissions in manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Hey Jagan, Are you solved your problem? I want to do the same operation but I am not able to do that. I want to get currently used satellite info as well as latitude and longitude from using NMEAListener. So can you please do me a favor, can you please share your code so that I can found my mistake and I can get more idea from that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Change your provider to GPS_PROVIDER.

You can get the nmea sentence by Gps provider.

Change this line

```
     **lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000,10,this);**
```

to

```
     **lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000,10,this);**
```

Now check in onNmeaReceived() method.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a NmeaListener

```
  public class SampleNMEA extends Activity implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener,GpsStatus.NmeaListener{
LocationManager lm;
TextView output;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out);
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000,10,this);
    final Location location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


    output.append("\nBelow Data is about the your location:");

    output.append("\n\n\nLatit:"+location.getLatitude());
    output.append("\n\nLongitude:"+location.getLongitude());
    output.append("\n\nTime: "+location.getTime());
   //add listener here
    lm.AddNmeaListener(this);





}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Samsung Galaxy Spica and yes, it doesn't work. However, I've installed 'ultra gps logger' ([link](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/ultra-gps-logger_ytsy.html)) and NMEA data is correctly read. Perhaps author of this tool used different solution for reading NMEA which means that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `addNmeaListener(GpsStatus.NmeaListener)` to set that class as a listener? If not, you should!

To do so, call it like `lm.addNmeaListener(this);`.

Good luck &
Regards

Comment: I tried this also but its not responding properly.. simply the application saying "force Close" what i need to change for this any permission required in manifest file.

Comment: You need to add permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to your Activity. But besides "Force Close", the log entry should provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion being reached in [this discussion here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7321#c25), is that **NMEA doesn't work on some phones** (the onNmeaReceived event never fires). ...but would love to be corrected on this.

Answer (score 0):

If fakeGps is in list of installed apps, be sure to delete it and **restart** device in order to start receiving Nmea info. You can install free Nmea Info monitor from play market to test Nmea receiver on your device.